# Chef installing uwsgi libiconv.so.2 no such file or directory

Tags: python, pip, chef-infra, uwsgi

I am trying to setup a Django server with `uwsgi`. When installing just `uwsgi` using [`poise-python`](https://github.com/poise/poise-python) with the following recipe:

```
python_runtime '3'

python_package 'uwsgi' do
    python '3'
end
```

When I login to the machine and just run `uwsgi` without any options, it will throw an error:

```
uwsgi: error while loading shared libraries: libiconv.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I checked the libraries and `libiconv.so.2` was not installed as so:

```
sudo ldconfig -p | grep libiconv
```

However, when I reinstall it as follows:

```
sudo pip uninstall uwsgi
sudo pip install uwsgi
```

The `uwsgi` command works again. What is weird is that when I check if `libiconv.so.2` is installed, it is still not installed.

How should I tell chef to install `uwsgi` properly without using `execute` to run the commands I did?

Note: I am using test kitchen and the virtual environment has been reset before running any commands. The os is debian 8.6.

Comment: iconv may be embedded into python virtualenv so ldconfig may not show it at all. It's a long shot, but is it possible that native python debian package is in conflict with runtime installed by poise?

Comment: @SzymonSzypulski What do you mean by python virtualenv? I did not setup any python virtual environment. I also don't understand what you mean by a conflict between the native python Debian and python poise runtime. Are you trying to say that the python 3 installed by poise is in conflict with the Debian python?

Comment: Yes, poise python may be in conflict with system python. I've mentioned python's [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/), but I didn't noticed you don't use, it's supported by poise python and it allows you to isolate your environment. Try it may be. It's also supported by uwsgi.

Comment: @SzymonSzypulski I was using a virtual environment at the start. I thought it was responsible for the errors but I was wrong. I doubt that it is in conflict with my system's python since the kitchen environment does not use python 3 at all.

Comment: Don't you have python 2 installed there? What is output of `which python` and `which pip`.

Comment: @SzymonSzypulski I think you meant something else. It returns `/usr/bin/python` and `/usr/local/bin/pip` respectively. However, my system's python (2.7) does not have pip, as shown using `python -m pip` but `python3.4 -m pip` works.

Comment: That was missleading, sorry. Have you looked at output of `ldd \`which uwsgi\`` after poise install and after manual reinstallation?

Comment: @MoonCheesez so you're 'default' python on command line is 2.7, uwsgi is installed in the 3.4, I suspect when you run uwsgi it use python2.7 paths and can't find its libraries...

Answer (score 16):

This works for me:

`conda install -c conda-forge libiconv`

ref: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/libiconv

Comment: I think this is a good solution for someone installed uwsgi by following command.


`$ conda install -c conda-forge uwsgi`

Answer (score 1):

got the same error, when testing in the kitchen.
`libconv` located at `/opt/chef/embedded/lib/`, so u need to include the path to `ldconfig`:

```
root@dokken:/# journalctl -u uwsgi
-- Logs begin at Fri 2018-01-26 08:59:50 UTC, end at Fri 2018-01-26 09:03:53 UTC
. --
Jan 26 09:03:53 dokken systemd[1]: Starting uWSGI...
Jan 26 09:03:53 dokken uwsgi[2789]: /opt/venv/bin/uwsgi: error while loading s
hared libraries: libiconv.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
directory
Jan 26 09:03:53 dokken systemd[1]: uwsgi.service: control process exited,
code=exited status=127
Jan 26 09:03:53 dokken systemd[1]: Failed to start uWSGI.
Jan 26 09:03:53 dokken systemd[1]: Unit uwsgi.service entered failed state
.
root@dokken:/# find /opt/ -name 'libiconv.so.2'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/libiconv.so.2
root@dokken:/# echo '/opt/chef/embedded/lib/' >> /etc/ld.so.conf
root@dokken:/# ldconfig
root@dokken:/# cat /etc/ld.so.conf
include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf

/opt/chef/embedded/lib/
root@dokken:/# service uwsgi start
root@dokken:/# ps axu  | grep uwsgi
root      2813  0.2  0.4  50876  8616 ?        S    09:05   0:00 /opt/venv/bin/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/uwsgi.ini
root      2814  0.0  0.5 201360 10276 ?        Sl   09:05   0:00 /opt/venv/bin/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/uwsgi.ini
root      2815  0.0  0.5 201360 10276 ?        Sl   09:05   0:00 /opt/venv/bin/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/uwsgi.ini
root      2821  0.0  0.0  11128   932 pts/0    S+   09:05   0:00 grep uwsgi
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 3 years late. Sort answer:

```
yum install libxml2-devel
```

corrected this problem for me (and might be helpful for anyone else using old cookbooks with old chef)

I was trying to install graphite with an older version of the chef cookbook with the same results as the original poster.

```
ldd /usr/local/bin/uwsgi 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffcdf53f000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f83286fa000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f83283f8000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f83281f4000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f8327fde000)
    libpcre.so.1 => /lib64/libpcre.so.1 (0x00007f8327d7c000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib64/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f8327b77000)
    libssl.so.1.0.0 => not found
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => not found
    libxml2.so.2 => /lib64/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f832780d000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib64/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f83275e7000)
    libiconv.so.2 => not found
    libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f83273e4000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f83271ad000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8326de0000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f8328916000)
    libfreebl3.so => /lib64/libfreebl3.so (0x00007f8326bdd000)
```

All of the *not found* are in `/opt/chef/embedded/lib` and my thought was that somehow the linker for pip was using `/opt/chef/embedded/lib/pkgconfig` instead of (or in addition to) the default system paths.

*libiconv* does not seem to be used in CentOS 7, but is included in the `/opt/chef/embedded/lib/pkgconfig` files for libxml-2.0, libxslt and libexslt ... which lead me to *libxml2-devel*.